# Is there a biography of Pavel Mif?

Tags: china, communism

[Pavel Mif](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pavel_Mif) by all Chinese accounts was a ruthless scheming Napoleon (the one in animal farm). Fortunate to the Chinese, Mif was later purged by Stalin. I wonder what sort of family he was from; where he was raised, etc.

Comment: I'm working from my phone, so can't really translate atm, but a quick search turned up [this book](https://archive.org/stream/KommunistischeParteiChinasImKampfe1937/KommunistischeParteiChinasImKampfe_1937#page/n1/mode/2up) on Archive.org by Mikhail Alexandrovich Fortus (Pavel Mif).

Comment: Why is this figure controversial?

Comment: English Wikipedia has his short biography, Russian Wikipedia, has a bit more. What do "all Chinese accounts" say about him?

Comment: In 1929, the one who had Chinese respect was Bukharin; Mif was BukHarin's antagonist. Mif was forceful and oppressive and was considered by Chinese students as Stalin's stooge who installed a Chinese stooge of his own and bungled Chinese affairs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As with many Soviet activists who did not get to publish their memoirs, early life of Pavel Mif (real name - Mikhail Alexandrovich Fortus) is a mystery. The only thing that is known for sure - he was born in 1901 in Bolshaya Alekseevka village of the Kherson Governorate of Russian Empire. His surname indicates that he might be a Jew, but that's not certain.

Data on his biography is better available from his adulthood, starting with 1920, when he enrolled in Sverdlov Communist institute. For example, there's [this article from 1972 in Russian](http://portalus.ru/modules/travelling/rus_readme.php?subaction=showfull&id=1484131819&archive=&start_from=&ucat=&), that deals with his work as a sinologist and a Comintern member. It points to Mif's critique of Mao and his faction as a reason for a negative opinion on Mif in China, but it might be biased against China in general, as it was written at the height of Sino-Soviet split.